# Get Learning Rate from <tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.learning_rate_schedule.CosineDecay> Object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, learning-rate

How can I get the value of the learning rate updated at each `on_train_batch_begin`?

```py
lr_decayed_fn = tf.keras.experimental.CosineDecay(initial_lr, decay_steps)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=lr_decayed_fn))
```

I tried this way

```py
def on_train_batch_begin (self, batch, logs = None):
    lr = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)
```

but I get `<tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.learning_rate_schedule.CosineDecay object at 0x7f ...>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a function as a learning rate or an object subclassing `LearningRateScheduler`, you need to call that function (or Callable) with the current training step to get the learning rate. You can get the current training step by using the [`iterations`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer#attributes_1) attribute of the optimizer.

```
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

    def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
        lr = tf.keras.backend.get_value(
            self.model.optimizer.lr(self.model.optimizer.iterations)
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your approach works perfectly.